# Why when I try to compile it tells me that some plugin is missing when they are all there?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly, pom.xml, maven-plugin

Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit."lts-ear-1.0.0-Alpha41-SNAPSHOT.ear"."lts-core.jar".component.CabinLayoutManagerImpl.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance

Problem here

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.1.Final:deploy (default) on project lts-ear: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"lts-ear-1.0.0-Alpha35-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"lts-core.jar\".component.CabinLayoutManagerImpl.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
[ERROR]     Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"lts-ear-1.0.0-Alpha35-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"lts-core.jar\".deploymentCompleteService"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"lts-ear-1.0.0-Alpha35-SNAPSHOT.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"lts-ear-1.0.0-Alpha35-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"lts-core.jar\".deploymentCompleteService]"]}}}
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :lts-ear
```

The pom is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>aero.navblue.nperformance.lts</groupId>
        <artifactId>lts-ng</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-Alpha41-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>lts-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- LTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aero.navblue.nperformance.lts</groupId>
            <artifactId>lts-war</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aero.navblue.nperformance.lts</groupId>
            <artifactId>lts-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <!-- Hack to replace placeholders in non-build resources. -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/..</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>sonar-project.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>9990</port>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>undeploy</id>
                        <phase>${cleanup.phase}</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>undeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <ignoreMissingDeployment>true</ignoreMissingDeployment>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>${deployment.phase}</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i expect this working

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] yoru question to include the full error message as properly formatted text.

Comment: There should be some log messages in the server logs.

Comment: Thanks, i change the image for code format like you say

Comment: Did you find anything in your server logs? There should be more details there.